# hook_mail_alter() - how to access the "contact admin" form fields?

Tags: 7, hooks, emails

In Drupal 7.10 I have the [/contact](http://preferans.de/contact) form open to anyone and would liketo add the **Reply-To** header to the mail message.

How do I get the value of the e-mail address field in the /contact form - both for guests and registered users?

Here is what I'm trying:

```
function your_module_mail_alter(&$message) {
  if ( $message['id'] == 'contact_page_mail' ) {
     $message['headers']['Reply-to'] = YYY;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this in hook_form_alter() instead of hook_mail_alter(). You can likely then run your own parameters into drupal_mail().

I would recommend not using this contact form, though, since it's terribly limited in terms of functionality. Why not use a Webform at /contact where you can specify all of these settings and do potentially cooler things too, like pre-filling fields for logged in users?